# Маршрут перекрывает другой маршрут

Tags: php, laravel

На сайте должен быть маршрут для просмотра списка всех товаров, а также маршрут для просмотра отдельного товара, и маршруты для просмотра разных страниц.

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('site.home');
Route::get('/contacts', 'ContactController@index')->name('site.contacts');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'products'], function(){
    Route::get('/electromobili', 'CarController@index')->name('site.electro');//список всех товаров
    Route::get('/diesel', 'CarController@index')->name('site.diesel');//список всех товаров
    Route::get('/{mark}', 'CarController@show')->name('site.show');//отдельный товар
});
```

**CarController**

```
class CarController extends Controller {
    public function index(Request $request) {
        return view('site.cars.index');
    }

    public function show(Request $request, Mark $mark){

        return view('site.cars.show');
    }
}
```

Если перейти по ссылке `/products/diesel` то срабатывает маршрут `CarController@index` `site.diesel` как и должно быть,
а если перейти по ссылке `/products/electromobili` то выдаёт ошибку 404, и выполняется такой запрос

```
select * from `marks` where `id` = 'electromobili' limit 1
```

маршрут `site.show` , а по идее должен был выполниться маршрут `site.electro`
тоже самое, если перейти по ссылке `/products/nissan` то выдаёт ошибку 404, и выполняется такой запрос

```
select * from `marks` where `id` = 'nissan' limit 1
```

маршрут `site.show`, хотя такая марка есть `nissan` в базе.
**таблица marks**
id, name, alias
nissan прописан в поле `alias`.
Почему выдаёт эту ошибку и как правильно обрабатывать показ марок списком (index) и на отдельной странице (show)?

если в маршрут добавить имя колонки `alias`

```
Route::get('/{mark:alias}', 'CarController@show')->name('site.show');
```

то ссылка `/products/electromobili` всё-равно выдаёт ошибку 404,
но ссылка `/products/nissan` уже не выдаёт ошибку.
Подскажите, как нужно сделать, чтобы работала ссылка `/products/electromobili` ?

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'products'], function(){
    Route::get('/{category:alias}', 'CarController@index')->name('site.electromobili');
    Route::get('/{mark:alias}', 'CarController@show')->name('site.show');
});
```

**CarController**

```
public function index(Request $request, Category $category) {
    dump($category);
    $generalData = $this->general->getData();
    return view('site.cars.index')
        ->with($generalData);
}

public function show(Request $request, Mark $mark){
    dump($mark);
    return view('site.cars.show');
}
```

если добавить такой маршрут `/{category:alias}`, тогда не срабатывает маршрут `{mark:alias}`, т.к. в категориях и марках может быть одинаковые значения в колонке `alias`
т.е. если перейти по ссылке `/products/nissan`, то сработает действие `index` ({category:alias}), а нужно чтобы сработало действие `show`

Comment: Как вы хотите, не получится, потому что Laravel рассматривает маршруты по совпадению. Совпало - выбрал, нет - пошёл дальше. В Вашем случае помогут только префиксы.

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar, а подскажите, как именно тут могут помочь префиксы?

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar, неужели с таким продвинутым маршрутизатором это так сложно реализовать?

Comment: я понять не могу, почему не сделать один маршрут `Route::get('/{product}', 'CarController@index')->name('site.products.index');` Под данный маршрут попадет и электромобили, и дизель, и все остальные ваши категории машин.